# Type casting error and constructor

Tags: c#, .net, casting, static-typing

I have two classes

```
 public class A
    {
        public A()
        {

        }
    }

    public class B:A
    {
        public B()
        {

        }
    }
```

and it the code in Main is as follows

```
    A oa = new B();
    B ob = new A();
```

Here line 1 compiles successfully while line 2 displays typecasting error.  Why this happens. What exactly happens when `new B()` and `new A()` gets called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly happens when new B() and
>   new A() gets called?

- `new A()` constructs an object of type `A` on the heap and returns a reference to it.
- `new B()` constructs an object of type `B` on the heap and returns a reference to it.

> Here line 1 compiles successfully
>   while line 2 displays typecasting
>   error. Why this happens.

Since `B` subclasses `A`, it is valid for a reference of type `A` to refer to an object of run-time type `B`. After all, `B` is simply a "special case" of `A`.

However, the converse is not true, because not all `A`s can be considered `B`s. 
Although this is strictly enforced by C#'s *safe* type-system even if there is no "real" incompatibility, the reasons for such restrictions are natural. Imagine, for example, that `B` declared a property `public int Foo {get; set;}`.
How would you expect this to behave:

```
B ob = new A();
ob.Foo = 5;
```

This is clearly illogical: the *real* object that the reference is referring to has no such property. Consequently, the compiler prohibits such constructs.

Now imagine you changed your code to:

`B b = (B)new A();`

Here, you are telling the compiler that the object created, will, at *run-time*, be assignable to a reference of type `B`. This will compile fine, but since the assertion is clearly incorrect,  a run-time `InvalidCastException` will be thrown.

To summarize, C#'s type system (if you ignore `dynamic` and a few special cases) is both *static* and *safe*: you will not successfully be able to treat a concrete instance of `A` as though it were of type `B`.

Answer (score 7):

You have declared a variable of type `B`, and then attempted to assign a value of type `A` to it. You have defined `B` to be a kind of `A`, but that doesn't mean that all `A`'s are `B`'s.

Think of it like this:

```
class Animal { }
class Dog : Animal { }
class Cat : Animal { }
```

You can do `Animal rex = new Dog()`, because all dogs are animals, but not `Dog fido = new Animal()`, because not all animals are dogs.